# redirecionamento de uma servlet para jsp

Tags: java, mvc, jsp, servlet-3

estou fazendo um projeto para o me curso de uma pagina de cadastro, onde estou tentando realizar a validação dos campos seguindo o padrão mvc. Com isso quero que a validação aconteça na camada controller

```
public class FornecedorService {
    private FornecedorDao fornecedorDao;
    private String errorMessage;

    public FornecedorService() throws SQLException {
        fornecedorDao = new FornecedorDao();
    }

    public boolean cadastrarFornecedor(Fornecedor fornecedor) throws SQLException {
        // Realize as validações antes de inserir o fornecedor
        if (!validateTelefone(fornecedor.getNumTelefone())) {
            errorMessage = "Número de telefone inválido.";
            return false;
        }

        if (!validateCEP(fornecedor.getCep())) {
            errorMessage = "CEP inválido.";
            return false;
        }

        if (!validateCNPJ(fornecedor.getCnpj())) {
            errorMessage = "CNPJ inválido.";
            return false;
        }

        return fornecedorDao.inserirFornecedor(fornecedor);
    }

    private boolean validateTelefone(String telefone) {
        // Remove espaços em branco e caracteres não numéricos
        telefone = telefone.replaceAll("\\s+", "").replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");

        // Verifica se o número de telefone possui o formato adequado
        // Exemplo de formatos válidos: (99) 99999-9999, (99) 9999-9999, 99999-9999, 9999999999, 99 99999999
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(?:\\(\\d{2}\\)\\s?)?\\d{4,7}[-\\s]?\\d{4}$");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(telefone);
        return matcher.matches();
    }

    private boolean validateCNPJ(String cnpj) {
        cnpj = cnpj.replaceAll("\\s+", "").replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");

        if (cnpj.length() != 14) {
            return false;
        }

        // Verifica se todos os dígitos são iguais (caso inválido)
        if (cnpj.matches("^(\\d)\\1+$")) {
            return false;
        }

        // Verifica se o CNPJ é válido usando o algoritmo de validação
        // ...

        return true;
    }

    private boolean validateCEP(String cep) {
        cep = cep.replaceAll("\\s+", "").replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");

        // Verifica se o CEP possui exatamente 8 dígitos numéricos
        if (cep.length() != 8) {
            return false;
        }

        // Verifica se o CEP é válido usando uma expressão regular
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[0-9]{5}-?[0-9]{3}$");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(cep);
        return matcher.matches();
    }
```

onde é criado as validacoes e passa para o servlet

```
package controllerjsp;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import classes.Fornecedor;
import services.FornecedorService;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class CadastroFornecedorServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/CadastroFornecedorServlet")
public class CadastroFornecedorServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private FornecedorService fornecedorService;

    public void init() throws ServletException {
        super.init();
        try {
            fornecedorService = new FornecedorService();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String nome = request.getParameter("nome_cad");
        String numTelefone = request.getParameter("numTelefone_cad");
        String email = request.getParameter("email_cad");
        String senha = request.getParameter("senha_cad");
        String numero = request.getParameter("numero_cad");
        String cep = request.getParameter("cep_cad");
        String cnpj = request.getParameter("cnpj_cad");
        String contaBancaria = request.getParameter("contaBancaria_cad");

        Fornecedor fornecedor = new Fornecedor();
        fornecedor.setNome(nome);
        fornecedor.setNumTelefone(numTelefone);
        fornecedor.setEmail(email);
        fornecedor.setSenha(senha);
        fornecedor.setNumero(numero);
        fornecedor.setCep(cep);
        fornecedor.setCnpj(cnpj);
        fornecedor.setContaBancaria(contaBancaria);

        try {
            boolean cadastroSucesso = fornecedorService.cadastrarFornecedor(fornecedor);
            if (cadastroSucesso) {
                response.sendRedirect("pages/LoginFornecedor.jsp");
            } else {
                String errorMessage = fornecedorService.getErrorMessage();
                request.setAttribute("cadastroError", errorMessage);
                response.sendRedirect("pages/CadastroFornecedor.jsp");
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            String errorMessage = "Erro ao cadastrar fornecedor: " + e.getMessage();
            request.setAttribute("cadastroError", errorMessage);
            response.sendRedirect("pages/CadastroFornecedor.jsp");
        }

    }
}
```

sendo assim gostaria de saber como posso fazer para passar para a minha pagina jsp quando um dos campos forem preenchidos de forma errado e o usuário seja informado do erro através de um pop up

se puderem me dar dicas de como fazer essa funcionalidade

Answer (score -2):

Pensando em um alert do js pode fazer algo assim:

```
String errorMessage = "Erro ao cadastrar fornecedor: " + e.getMessage();
request.setAttribute("cadastroError", "<script>alert('" + errorMessage + "');</script>");
```

Eu usava uma div pra fazer isso, fica feio no codigo mas é funcional:

```
request.setAttribute("cadastroError", "<div class=\"alert alert-danger\" id=\"foo\">"
                + "<strong> "+ errorMessage +" </strong>"
                + "</div>" 
                +"<script>$().ready(function() {\n" +
                    "   setTimeout(function () {\n" +
                    "       $('#foo').hide(); // \"foo\" é o id do elemento que deseja manipular.\n" +
                    "   }, 15000); // O valor é representado em milisegundos.\n" +
                    "});</script>");
        }
```

Lembre-se de ter jquery e bootstrap no projeto.

Caso queira fazer um 'pop-up' estilizado, tente usar algum exemplo da página do
[bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/modal/)